# Exporting pictures in their correct size when using Grid

Tags: export, image-processing

I have a large number of pictures, and I need to place each three of them in a grid with a certain layout. For example, if I have the following pictures:

```
p1 = 
  Import["http://images4.fanpop.com/image/photos/21900000/Beautiful-\
    Pictures-_-beautiful-pictures-21967793-1024-768.jpg"];
p2 = 
  Import["http://static.ddmcdn.com/gif/ice-ice-babies-pictures-2.jpg"];
p3 = 
  Import["http://latimesphoto.files.wordpress.com/2012/08/la-0824-pin01.jpg"];
```

The image dimensions of each is as follows:

```
ImageDimensions[#] & /@ {p1, p2, p3}

(* {{1024, 768}, {622, 468}, {970, 647}}  *)
```

I have resized the first 2 pictures:

```
{p11, p22} = ImageResize[#, 300] & /@ {p1, p2};
```

and now I want to place them together in one picture and then export them.
I have tried Grid as follows:

```
all = Grid[{{p3, Column[{p11, p22}]}}]
Export["all.jpg", all]
```

The problem is that, `Grid` does not return the pictures in their correct size. So when I export, the result will be very small as seen in the pictures bellow.
How can I get `Grid` to return the three pictures sized as I want?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Original answer

By default FrontEnd resizes graphics down inside list-like constructs. To prevent this inside `Grid`, set `BaseStyle -> ImageSizeMultipliers -> 1` option for `Grid`:

```
all = Grid[{{p3, Column[{p11, p22}]}}, BaseStyle -> ImageSizeMultipliers -> 1];
```

### Response to Mr.Wizard's comments

As Mr.Wizard notes in the comments, the `ImageSizeMultipliers -> 1` does not fix another feature related to `Image` itself, citing the Documentation page for `Image`:

> With `Magnification->Automatic`, smaller images are typically
>   displayed at larger magnifications, and large images are reduced to
>   fit within available notebook or other display areas.

`Magnification->Automatic` is the default option of `Image`, so if the whole `Grid` does not fit the screen area, all the images (sequentially starting from the largest one) are rescaled to fit the screen area. So more general workaround is:

```
all = Grid[{{p3, Column[{p11, p22}]}}] /. x_Image :> Image[x, Magnification -> 1]
```

If one wish to have `Images` always displayed and exported at their true sizes independently of any local or global Notebook's and FrontEnd's settings for the `Magnification` option, it is possible to achieve this by setting `Magnification` locally using `Style`:

```
Style[
   Grid[{{p3, Column[{p11, p22}]}}] /. x_Image :> Image[x, Magnification -> 1], 
   Magnification -> 1]
```

Now the magnification will be no longer affected by any local or global settings, for example

```
Magnify[%, 2]
```

Will display everything exactly at the original magnification.

Comment: Thanks a lot. this is what I am looking for.

Comment: At least in version 7 this doesn't work (entirely).  Rather than rendering large images at full pixel size it results in a scaling where all images fit on one screen width.  Useful, but not what was requested.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I have added another, more general method.

Comment: Indeed, that jogged a memory.  Note that to override a Notebook magnification you'll also need a `Style[. . ., Magnification -> 1]`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks a lot to Mr. Wizard. your comments made the answers more solid and clear.

Answer (score 3):

In general, you can also use the `ImageSize->All` option for images to ensure that an image is always displayed full sized, even if it's in a list. So you could write:

```
all = Grid[{{Image[p3, ImageSize -> All], 
Column[{Image[p11, ImageSize -> All], 
  Image[p22, ImageSize -> All]}]}}]
```

(but I realize that's more typing in this specific case.)

Comment: This method works for me.  You can simplify its application with this: `Grid[{{p3, Column[{p11, p22}]}} /. x_Image :> Image[x, ImageSize -> All]]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard this method and your simplification are very nice.