# Inconsistent image sizing with Grid and Row?

Tags: image-processing, image, grid-layouts

Can anyone explain why `Row` and `Grid` don't size the image correctly and consistently to `300` as specified in `ImageResize`?

```
image = ImageResize[Import["ExampleData/lena.tif"], 300];
image
Row[{image}]
Grid[{{image}}]
Row[{"abcd", image}]
Grid[{{"abcd", image}}]
```

[image]

`GraphicsGrid` doesn't seem to help either.

Any workarounds to do so?

Comment: because you can paste images and use them as expressions just like anything else. The actual image size information is stored in the option `ImageSizeRaw`. When you say "`GraphicGrid` doesn't help either" what exactly do you want as the outcome?

Comment: I've received (as of this comment) 2 useful but different workarounds.  Mr.Wizard's the simplest and most direct and Mike's a bit more versatile in that it gives one additional control for sizing.  How to chose?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard restores the actual image size without you have to know that actual size so would be a preferred option if that is all you need to do.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch - We should have a badge for sportsmanship!  Many thanks.

Comment: just calling it the way i see it

Comment: @Mike [PIF'ed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pay_it_forward) to kguler. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another approach ([from this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/76695/125)) is to re-set the value of the option [`ImageSizeMultipliers`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageSizeMultipliers.html) to `{1.,1.}` :

> [image]

```
image = ImageResize[Import["ExampleData/lena.tif"], 250];
image2 = ImageResize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}], 150];
```

With the default settings

```
image
image2
Grid[{{"abcd", image, image2}}]
```

gives

[image]

After evaluating

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], ImageSizeMultipliers -> {1., 1.}]
```

anywhere in the notebook, we get

[image]

You can reset the option value to its default using:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], ImageSizeMultipliers -> {.5, .25}]
```

An alternative, more cumbersome, approach is to wrap each object with `Style[#, ImageSizeMultipliers->{1.,1.}`:

```
dontResizeF = Style[#, ImageSizeMultipliers -> {1., 1.}] &;
image
image2
Grid[{{"abcd", dontResizeF@image, dontResizeF@image2}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this.  This gives one a much better idea about what Mathematica might actually do under the hood.  It does seem odd, that the default values of `ImageSizeMultiplier` don't equal `{1.,1.}`.

Comment: Jagra, my pleasure. The default value makes using images/graphs in `Input` cells more convenient. I agree with you that, for output cells, default value of `1` would make more sense.

Comment: I've decided to select your answer as the best one (sorry @Mr.Wizard), because while the others provide workarounds, this one actually provides some insight and explanation of why the problem occurs.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Jagra No problem!  I encouraged kguler to (re)post this here.  I agree it is the best answer.  For application to one item at a time I'll still use `Pane`, but it is a side-effect rather than the specific purpose of that construct, unlike the Option described here.

Comment: @Jagra, thank you for the Accept.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard -- I think I participate on this site every bit as much for the generosity of spirit as I do for the information (and I hugely value the information).

Answer (score 11):

My standard<sup>[(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11987/121)</sup> work-around for this problem is to add [`Pane`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pane.html):

```
Grid[{{Pane@image}}]
Row[{"abcd", Pane@image}]
Grid[{{"abcd", Pane@image}}]
```

[image]

A default characteristic of `Pane` is that it still allows resizing its contents to fit the window width of the Notebook.  I find this a desirable default behavior.  However if clipping is preferred you can specify an absolute width for `Pane`, or use [`ImageSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSize.html) as Mike Honeychurch proposed.

```
Grid@{Table[image, {2}]}
Grid@{Table[Pane@image, {2}]}
Grid@{Table[Pane@image, {3}]}
Grid@{Table[Pane[image, 300], {3}]}
```

[image]

For more control see:

- [How do I display imported images at actual size?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8583/121)
- [Exporting pictures in their correct size when using Grid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/49230/121)

Answer (score 8):

As per my comment you will note that images can be pasted into notebooks and used as expressions. They are not rendered at full size but the size information is stored as an option. If all you want to do is have `Row` and `Grid` render something to the same specific size then try `Show`:

```
Row[{"abcd", Show[image, ImageSize -> 300]}]
Grid[{{"abcd", Show[image, ImageSize -> 300]}}]
```