# Graphical output sizes

Tags: plotting

Is there any way to control the size of output graphics when using simple Grid command?

Here is an example code:

```
Do[Subscript[a, i] = Plot[Sin[x + Pi*0.25*i], {x, 0, 12*Pi}], {i,3}];
Subscript[a, 1]
Transpose[Table[{Subscript[a, i]}, {i, 3}]] // MatrixForm
```

Outputting a single plot returns a full size object, outputting a stack returns reduced size ones.

Using GraphicsGrid is not a solution in my case, because I have a huge stack of plots which results in huge size of image to build and takes a very long time to complete.

Comment: Does adding the option ImageSize->n for some suitable value of n to each of your plots fix this for you?

Comment: Please add sample code to make this question answerable and more useful.

Comment: Great thanks for all replies!
I added code to my question above.
I usually use Grid or MatrixForm to visualise a stack of graphs, ImageSize returns error when using with latter functions.

Comment: I would recommend using `Grid`, which offers lots of layout options.

Comment: I use `Grid` too, but do you know exactly how it is possible to control the size of the plot there?
There is an `ItemSize` option in Grid, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [(72573)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72573/121)

Comment: Does it help to use the option `ImageSize -> Scaled[0.7]` (or whatever factor you wish) inside `Plot`? That will behave more nicely if you change the window size than does an absolute setting for `ImageSize` in points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My preferred work-around for this is to add [`Pane`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pane.html) to each graphic.  This prevents the default shrinking.   It however still allows resizing to fit the screen width, which usually for me is a positive attribute.  If you specify an absolute [`ImageSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSize.html) such as the default 360 no resizing takes place and the graphics are clipped by the Notebook window.

```
{Array[Pane @ Subscript[a, #] &, 2]} // Grid
{Array[Pane @ Subscript[a, #] &, 3]} // Grid
{Array[Show[Subscript[a, #], ImageSize -> 360] &, 3]} // Grid
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** You can re-set the value of the option `ImageSizeMultipliers` at the notebook, front-end-session or front-end levels.

Default value this option is

```
Options[EvaluationNotebook[], ImageSizeMultipliers]
(* {ImageSizeMultipliers -> {0.5, 0.25}} *)
```

If you set this option value to `{1,1}` using

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], ImageSizeMultipliers -> {1, 1}]
```

then all graphics/images are in the current notebook are re-rendered in their original size:
[image]

---

**Original post:**

You can wrap each plot with `Style[#, ImageSizeMultipliers -> {1, 1}]&` to ensure that graphics are rendered in their original size inside other constructs (see [ImageSizeMultipliers](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageSizeMultipliers.html)).

```
plots = Table[Plot[Sin[x + Pi*0.25*i], {x, 0, 12*Pi}], {i, 3}];
plots[[1]]
{plots} // Grid
{Style[#, ImageSizeMultipliers -> {1, 1}] & /@ plots} // Grid
```

[image]

Comment: kguler, do you think this should be closed as a duplicate of [(72573)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72573/121)?  I believe your (unique) answer is equally valid there.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, as it stands it _is_ a special case of the linked q/a. Btw, if this q/a is closed as a duplicate, will it be deleted sometime in the future (if so, it would make sense to post my answer in the linked q/a), or does it stay?

Comment: Since the OP switched the Accept to my answer, which is indeed a duplicate, I think I shall close this.  Duplicates are not routinely deleted, though there is no promise that they will not some day be deleted.  Closed questions that are not duplicates I have been deleting at one year of age.  I encourage you to post this `ImageSizeMultipliers` method to 72573.

Answer (score 1):

```
plots = DateListPlot[CountryData[#, {"Population", {1800, 2020}}], 
     PlotLabel -> "population of " <> #, 
     ImageSize -> 250] & /@ {"Poland", "Austria", "Switzerland", 
    "Germany"};

GraphicsGrid[{{plots[[1]], plots[[2]]}, {plots[[3]], plots[[4]]}}, 
 ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

```
sol = Solve[{2 x + 3 y == 5, 3 x + 4 y == 11}];
xyVals = {x, y} /. sol;
p1 = Plot[(5 - 2 x)/3, {x, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> 5, Frame -> True, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> Small];
p2 = Plot[(11 - 3 x)/4, {x, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> 5, Frame -> True, 
   AspectRatio -> 1];
cp1 = ContourPlot[{2 x + 3 y == 5, 3 x + 4 y == 11}, {x, 12, 
    14}, {y, -6, -8}, 
   Epilog -> { Red, PointSize[Large], Point@xyVals}];
```

[image]

Comment: GraphicsGrid works fine, but it returns single solid picture! While Grid or //MatrixForm returns a combination of graphics, each of which may be edited manually

Comment: Else to be admitted, GraphicsGrid seems to work much slower than Grid