# Controlling the size of a Plot, ListPlot when using Grid view

Tags: plotting

Is there any way to control the size of output graphics when using simple Grid command?

Here is an example code:

```
Do[Subscript[a, i] = Plot[Sin[x + Pi*0.25*i], {x, 0, 12*Pi}], {i,3}];
Subscript[a, 1]
Transpose[Table[{Subscript[a, i]}, {i, 3}]] // MatrixForm
```

Outputting a single plot returns a full size object, outputting a stack returns reduced size ones.

Using GraphicsGrid is not a solution in my case, because I have a huge stack of plots which results in huge size of image to build and takes a very long time to complete.

Comment: I am going to combine this question with your earlier one: [(76421)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76421/121).  Please edit it such that the aspects of both questions that are important to you are contained in that one alone.  Thanks.